# Appending Text to Textbox in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell.  I am creating a program that is going to execute several SQL Server Stored Procedures.  The power shell code is creating a Windows Form with a Text Box.  As each step is completed I want to update the Text box. Below is my code where I am just testing appending to the text box.  In the setup of the box I append the line (" Test Text `r`n").   After the form is displayed I try to append the line (" Test Line 2 `r`n").   I cannot get the second line to show on the form. I have tried the $Form.Refresh().  No go.

```
Cls

# Load the .NET form classes
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.TextBox")

# Get the script path
$scriptPath = Split-Path ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)

# Establish the form
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Consolidation Program for Dillon School Districts"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(650,350) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.Icon = "$scriptPath\Icon.ico"


# Create the date text box label for the earliest date to consolidate
$objLabel_MergLable = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel_MergLable.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,90) 
$objLabel_MergLable.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$objLabel_MergLable.Text = "Merger Process Status"
$objLabel_MergLable.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel_MergLable)

# Create Merger Status Text Box
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.Multiline = $True
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.ScrollBars ="Vertical"
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,110) 
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(560,100) 
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.AppendText(" Test Text `r`n")
$objForm.Controls.Add($ObjTextBox_MergStatus)



# Show the form on the screen
$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()


$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.AppendText(" Test Line 2 `r`n")
```

Comment: This is really not a PowerShell issue. It's a misunderstanding about UX/UI design, control, and population. [So, really, spend the time getting up to speed on UX/UI concepts](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=winform+ux%2Fui+design). UX/UI design is a completely separate skillset (career path - Frontend developer) from PowerShell. Your UX/UI should just work, regardless of the backend/code-behind language, you'd use. Your backend/code-behind should just work to get data from and/or populate date to your UX/UI. btw, you can build PS GUI without doing form code.

Comment: I agree with @postanote frontend work in PowerShell is a tedious process, designing the UX/UI should be an after thought. Build your logic first (Functions etc) then wrap your GUI around it expanding your backend and frontend with exception handling. I also highly recommend using [POSHGUI](https://poshgui.com/Editor), the layout when copying the code may be a bit out but you tweak this in ISE etc, to control the form add events on the right and insert your code into the event handlers that are added.

Comment: Ditto, CraftyB, and that last link `[make things happen]` I gave is a link to the Youtube videos for what PoshGUI.com is and how to use it. Btw, there is a app you can use for this WinForm designer as an offline option. See [PSScriptPad](https://docs.poshtools.com/powershell-pro-tools-documentation/psscriptpad) from IronmanSofteware, the author of PowerShell Pro Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line fails to work because of where/how you are calling it.

Example refactor

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Drawing,
                        PresentationCore,
                        PresentationFramework,
                        System.Windows.Forms,
                        Microsoft.VisualBasic
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
 
$scriptPath = Split-Path ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)

$objForm               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text          = 'Consolidation Program for Dillon School Districts'
$objForm.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(650, 350)
$objForm.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$objForm.Icon          = '$scriptPath\Icon.ico'

$objLabel_MergLable          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel_MergLable.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35, 90)
$objLabel_MergLable.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$objLabel_MergLable.Text     = 'Merger Process Status'
$objLabel_MergLable.Font     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Arial', 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel_MergLable)

$ObjTextBox_MergStatus            = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.Multiline  = $True
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.ScrollBars = 'Vertical'
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.Location   = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35, 110)
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.Size       = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(560, 100)
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.AppendText("Test Text `r`n")
$objForm.Controls.Add($ObjTextBox_MergStatus)

$objForm.Add_Shown( { $objForm.Activate() })

$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.AppendText("Test Line 2 `r`n")

[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

If you are trying to do things on a form after the form is displayed, then you must have other elements (button, checkboxes, etc) that you tie [form events](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=winform%20button%20events) to, to [makes things happen](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=poshgui).

Example - but please study up on this to limit confusion, etc...

```
<# 
Code-Behind - this can be in a completely separate .ps1/psm1 file that 
you'd dot reference
#>

function Add-MoreText
{
    $ObjTextBox_MergStatus.AppendText("Test Line 2 `r`n")
}
 
$scriptPath = Split-Path ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)

Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Drawing,
                        PresentationCore,
                        PresentationFramework,
                        System.Windows.Forms,
                        Microsoft.VisualBasic
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$objForm               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text          = 'Consolidation Program for Dillon School Districts'
$objForm.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(650, 350)
$objForm.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$objForm.Icon          = '$scriptPath\Icon.ico'

$objLabel_MergLable          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel_MergLable.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35, 90)
$objLabel_MergLable.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$objLabel_MergLable.Text     = 'Merger Process Status'
$objLabel_MergLable.Font     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Arial', 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel_MergLable)

$ObjTextBox_MergStatus            = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.Multiline  = $True
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.ScrollBars = 'Vertical'
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.Location   = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35, 110)
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.Size       = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(560, 100)
$ObjTextBox_MergStatus.AppendText("Test Text `r`n")
$objForm.Controls.Add($ObjTextBox_MergStatus)

$Okbutton          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Okbutton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,80)
$Okbutton.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,30)
$Okbutton.Text     = 'Add Text'
$Okbutton.Add_Click({Add-MoreText})
$objForm.Controls.Add($Okbutton)

$objForm.Add_Shown( { $objForm.Activate() })

[void]$objForm.ShowDialog()
```